# How to alter values from table 1(field 1, field 2,...)into new table2 (field 1, field 2,..) in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, openerp-7

I am new to openerp/postgresql and trying to update columns in table 2 (hr_dependency) with respective values from table 1 (hr_employee) which is my master table of the system.

Actually I have no idea how to do that.

(table 1 has 126 columns including this and two tables are in one2many relationship)

```
    table 1 (hr_employee)
------------------------------
id,
mother_name,
m_occupation,
m_date_of_birth,
m_alive_or_dead,
father_name,
f_occupation,
m_date_of_birth,
f_alive_or_dead,


table 2 (hr_dependents)
----------------------------
id,
d_type,
d_name,
d_occupation,
d-date_of-birth,
d_sex,
d_alive_or_dead,
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a technical question, but more like some work snippet posted online. Could you elaborate what all you tried, and what error messages you received so that someone could point out where you're going wrong.

Comment: How are those two tables linked together? Through the `id` column? What are the primary keys of those tables? Is there a one-to-one relationship between those tables? Or is it a one-to-many (many hr_dependents link to one hr_employee?)